# Cannot connect to the Internet from my Mac but can do it from iPhone

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have an Asus RT-N12E router and I can connect to the Internet over WiFi using two different iPhones (neither is connected to the Internet using cellular data). However, I can’t connect to the Internet using my Mac (Catalina 10.15.5), even though I am connected to the WiFi network.

I can access the router’s GUI with my Mac, but can’t do that on my phones. The web GUI greets me with this message:

> The network cable is unplugged. Please ensure that the cable is plugged between RT-N12E WAN port and the modem. Please check if you need to change the Operation Mode.

Currently I have the Ethernet cable connected from my wall to the router’s LAN1 port. If I connect it to WAN, I don’t have Internet access at all, but connected to LAN1 at least my phones can reach the Internet.

The phones are in the 100.65.22.0/24 subnet, and my Mac is in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

I have already tried to fix this by:

- turning WiFi off and back on on my Mac
- restarting my Mac
- creating a new WiFi service on my Mac
- restarting the router
- factory reseting the router
- and changing the router’s mode from “Wireless router mode (Default)” to “Access Point (AP) mode”.

I can’t download new router firmware or upgrade my Mac because my Mac can’t connect to the Internet, so what else can I try?

Comment: You must plug the internet into the router's WAN port. It sounds like your service provider's IP address is being assigned directly to your phone instead of your router. Make sure you restart all your devices including your router after you swap the connection to the WAN port.

Comment: Try a hardware reset of your router. When it restarts, connect an Ethernet cable (known good) between the wall outlet and the WAN port of the router (as noted in the other comment). You should have Internet at the router and if not, call the ISP,

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick! I connected the cable to the WAN port, and then did a factory reset :) now everything works as expected